# More than one css class clickable in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, clickable

How can I do so that even "toggle_cart" is clickable in the same way as "clickerHeader"
but retains its hover effect (see arrow)?

please see http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/STE48/3

```
$('.eventMenu > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
            $('.eventMenu .js ul').hide();
            $(document).on("click", function(e) {
                var $elem = $(e.target);
                if ($elem.hasClass('clickerHeader')) {
                    $('.eventMenu .js ul').not($elem.next('ul')).hide();
                    $elem.next("ul").slideToggle();
                } else if (!$($elem).parents('.contentHolderHeader').length) {
                    //} else {
                    $('.eventMenu .js ul').hide();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hello,
Looked your change, but do not understand. I want "toggle_cart" will be clickable in the same way as "clickerHeader"?

Comment: is there any reason it is all within a li item?

Comment: The reason for that is that I will add more links, (to become a menu)

Comment: hmm...Is the togglecart arrow meant to open the language thing?

Comment: "toggle_cart" should be open "contentHolderHeader" which also "clickerHeader" must do (doing today).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap both elements in a div ..
http://jsfiddle.net/STE48/5/

```
.
```

Comment: Yes, but then stops fallback working in your example, if you do not have javascript activated, so then goes menu over to mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS add:

```
.eventMenu:hover .no-js .contentHolderHeader {
    display: block;
}
```

Also add a `display: none` to `div.eventMenu .contentHolderHeader`.

Replace the JS with:

```
$('.eventMenu > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
$(".toggle_cart").click(function(e){
    $(".contentHolderHeader").slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(".eventMenu").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){ 
    $(".contentHolderHeader").slideUp();
});
```

Remove the inner `ul` in the HTML.

Tested with/without JS: http://jsfiddle.net/vuF9n/2/

Comment: hi,
it is not right,
then the mnu not work without javascript (mouse over)
plus it does not go up when you click outside "contentHolderHeader".

Answer (score 0):

A minimal change to your existing code is to add the following two lines after the first line of your click function:

```
if ($elem.hasClass('toggle_cart'))
     $elem = $elem.next();
```

In other words, if the span with the arrow is clicked, pretend that actually the anchor element was clicked. In context:

```
        $(document).on("click", function(e) {
            var $elem = $(e.target);
            if ($elem.hasClass('toggle_cart'))
                $elem = $elem.next();
            if ($elem.hasClass('clickerHeader')) {
            // etc.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/STE48/6/