# Add extra class for link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, click

How can I do so that even "toggle_cart" is clickable in the same way as "clickerHeader" but retains its hover effect (see arrow)?

Both "toggle_cart" and "clickerHeader" should open "contentHolderHeader".

It is important to keep the script with the features available today and only do so "toggle_cart" is Also click.

please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/STE48/3)

```
 $('.eventMenu > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
            $('.eventMenu .js ul').hide();

            $(document).on("click", function(e) {
                var $elem = $(e.target);
                if ($elem.hasClass('clickerHeader')) {
                    $('.eventMenu .js ul').not($elem.next('ul')).hide();
                    $elem.next("ul").slideToggle();
                } else if (!$($elem).parents('.contentHolderHeader').length) {
                    //} else {
                    $('.eventMenu .js ul').hide();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hello,
I know that I should there, but the question has disappeared from my account (so I can not do that), but are on the site?

Comment: _"the question has disappeared from my account"_ - The other question shows up in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2941788/lars-holmqvist?tab=questions&sort=newest), and I was able to add [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20933688/615754) after following the link to your question that Saeed Py posted above.

Comment: hi,
exactly where in the code it shall in?

Comment: yes, as I said I can see question on the site,

but I go to my profile, so I do not see the question, and I am on the question so I can not change it, or write a comment.

Usually not post duplicate questions then it's silly, but I thought what should I do?

Comment: #nnnnnn, see your answer but can not answer. When it comes without java script so it is now down from the start, how do I get it to only go down on mouseover?

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/STE48/7/

Comment: Hello,
Thanks to your help, it works just as it should now :)
Thanks for the help!